# Let PShapes in an array rotate on its own axis in Processing

Tags: rotation, processing, translate

I have this code that basically reads each pixel of an image and redraws it with different shapes. All shapes will get faded in using a `sin()` wave.
Now I want to rotate every "Pixelshape" around its own axis (`shapeMode(CENTER)`) while they are faded in and the translate function gives me a headache in this complex way.

Here is the code so far:

```
void setup() {
  size(1080, 1350); 
  shapeMode(CENTER);
  img = loadImage("loremipsum.png");
…
}

void draw() {
    background(123);
    for (int gridX = 0; gridX < img.width; gridX++) {
    for (int gridY = 0; gridY < img.height; gridY++) {

      // grid position + tile size
      float tileWidth = width / (float)img.width;
      float tileHeight = height / (float)img.height;
      float posX = tileWidth*gridX;
      float posY = tileHeight*gridY;

      // get current color
      color c = img.pixels[gridY*img.width+gridX];

      // greyscale conversion
      int greyscale = round(red(c)*0.222+green(c)*0.707+blue(c)*0.071);
      int gradientToIndex = round(map(greyscale, 0, 255, 0, shapeCount-1));
    
      //FADEIN
      float wave = map(sin(radians(frameCount*4)), -1, 1, 0, 2);
      //translate(HEADACHE);
      rotate(radians(wave));
      shape(shapes[gradientToIndex], posX, posY, tileWidth * wave, tileHeight * wave);
    }
  }
```

I have tried many calculations but it just lets my sketch explode.
One that worked in another sketch where I tried basically the same but just in loop was (equivalent written):

```
translate(posX + tileWidth/2, posY + tileHeight/2);
```

I think I just don't get the matrix right? How can I translate them to its meant place?

Answer (score 3):

[`rotate`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) defines a rotation matrix and multiplies the current matrix by the rotation matrix. `rotate` therefore causes a rotation by (0, 0).
You have to center the rectangle around (0, 0), rotate it and move the rotated rectangle to the desired position with [`translate`](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html).

Since `translate` and `rotate` multiplies the current matrix by a new matrix, you must store and restore the matrix by [`pushMatrix()`](https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html) respectively [`popMatrix()`](https://processing.org/reference/popMatrix_.html).

The center of a tile is (`posX + tileWidth/2`, `posY + tileHeight/2`):

```py
pushMatrix();
translate(posX + tileWidth/2, posY + tileHeight/2);
rotate(radians(wave));
shape(shapes[gradientToIndex], 
    -tileWidth*wave/2, -tileHeight*wave/2,
    tileWidth * wave, tileHeight * wave);
popMatrix();
```

Comment: Hi Rabbid76 – thank you for your fast response! Really appreciate it!
Yes I had the same code for the center of each shape – but the way they get drawn in the shape functions just let everything explode unfortunately…

Comment: @Cyrill Why do you multiply `tileWidth` and `tileHeight` with `wave`? Did you try the code? Have you seen `shape(..., -tileWidth*wave/2, -tileHeight*wave/2, ...)`

Comment: Hi Rabbid, yes i checked the code – tried it – unfortunately it explodes…
I multiply "tileWidth" and "tileHeight" by wave so that each shape grows and shrinks… so that i animate the pattern… Its like a fade in on the sizing…
In your code the X and Y pos is also multiplied by the wave … I wanted let them in place…but: let them grow and shrink while rotating… :-)

Comment: @Cyrill You're right. `pushMatrix();`/`popMatrix();`

Answer (score 3):

Thank you very much @Rabbid76 – at first I just pasted in your idea and it went of crazy – then I added pushMatrix(); and popMatrix(); – turned out your translate(); code was in fact right!
Then I had to change the x and y location where every shape is drawn to 0,0,
And this is it! Now it works!
See the code here:

```
   float wave = map(sin(radians(frameCount*4)), -1, 1, 0, 2);
   pushMatrix();
   translate(posX + tileWidth/2, posY + tileHeight/2);
   rotate(radians(wave*180));
   shape(shapes[gradientToIndex], 0, 0, tileWidth*wave , tileHeight*wave );
   popMatrix();
```

PERFECT! Thank you so much!